# How to position wrapimages in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, graphics, positioning, wrapfigure

I'm a newbie to LaTeX and was working on a school assignment and thought it would look nice to have an image next to two tables instead of underneath them. Unfortunately, this proved more difficult than expected. I eventually worked out most of it using wrapfigures, but the image is still slightly in the wrong position. How can I position it correctly?

Here is the code:

```
%Tables are generated using tablesgenerator.com
\begin{table}[!t]

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \advance\leftskip1cm
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, angle =180, right]{picture.JPG}
\end{wrapfigure}
\advance\leftskip-1cm
\advance\rightskip-1cm
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
            Angular Amplitude \\ 
            (in cm from base)
        \end{tabular}& 30 Periods & Average Period \\
        1.5                                                                            & 39.55      & 1.32 sec.      \\
        3                                                                              & 39.67      & 1.32 sec.      \\
        4.5                                                                            & 39.76      & 1.33 sec.      \\
        6                                                                              & 39.98      & 1.33 sec.      \\
        7.5                                                                            & 39.84      & 1.33 sec.     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!t]
    \advance\leftskip-1cm
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
            Length of Pendulum\\ 
            (in cm)
        \end{tabular} & 30 Periods & Average Period \\
        20                                                                              & 26.91 sec. & 0.897 sec.     \\
        22                                                                              & 28.88 sec. & 0.963 sec.     \\
        26                                                                              & 31.40 sec. & 1.047 sec.     \\
        31                                                                              & 34.30 sec. & 1.143 sec.     \\
        35                                                                              & 35.82 sec. & 1.194 sec.    \\\\\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

*The Result*:
[image: The Result]

*The Desired Result*:
[image: The Desired Result]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to use `wrapfigure` is if you want text to flow around your image -- and even then it is a pain to use.

To place things besides each other, you can use minipages. In the example below I'm also using the `tblr` environment instead of a normal `tabular` environment. This makes it very easy to add multiline cells, so you don't have to use this ugly code with nested tables which the only generator gave you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{tblr}{lll}
        {Angular Amplitude \\ (in cm from base)}
        & {30\\ Periods} & {Average\\ Period} \\
        1.5                                                                            & 39.55      & 1.32 sec.      \\
        3                                                                              & 39.67      & 1.32 sec.      \\
        4.5                                                                            & 39.76      & 1.33 sec.      \\
        6                                                                              & 39.98      & 1.33 sec.      \\
        7.5                                                                            & 39.84      & 1.33 sec.     \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great example image!

Comment: @Skillmon :) The duck is already dressed up for next week!

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Fire_Aspect_5 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As well said,  `wrapfig` is a pain because there are several constrains for the correct use, as explained in the manual. One of these constrains, not specific to this package, is that you never should nest floats (i.e., never ever put a `figure` inside a `table`!).

I agree also that if the goal is to align at top  a <s>figure</s> image with a <s>table</s> tabular-like environment, then `wrapfig` is the wrong tool. But said that, and assuming that you really want the text to flow around the bottom of the image, you can control the vertical space for the wrap figure setting the number of lines  (the `[8]` in the MWE below) and set also `\intextsep` locally.

I changed the tabulars to fit automatically the space available after a change of the width of `wrapfigure`, but note that in that case should  change also the  number of lines accordingly, i..e.,  if you change the width of the wrap figure  to 50% or 30%, tabulars will adapt automatically, but you must increase/decrease the  `[8]` to the right number of lines due to thee new size of the image.

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,tabulary,booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
{\intextsep 5pt
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{wrapfigure} \par
\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}[t]{CCC}\toprule
 Angular Amplitude\par  (in cm  from base) & Thirty Periods & Average  Period \\\midrule
 1.5 & 39.55 & 1.32 sec. \\
 3 & 39.67 & 1.32 sec. \\
 4.5 & 39.76 & 1.33 sec. \\
 6 & 39.98 & 1.33 sec. \\
 7.5 & 39.84 & 1.33 sec. \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}\par
\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}[t]{CCC}\toprule
 Length of Pendulum  (in cm) & Thirty Periods & Average Period \\\midrule
 20 & 26.91 sec. & 0.897 sec. \\
 22 & 28.88 sec. & 0.963 sec. \\
 26 & 31.40 sec. & 1.047 sec. \\
 31 & 34.30 sec. & 1.143 sec. \\
 35 & 35.82 sec. & 1.194 sec. \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\section{Discusion}
\subsection{Definitions} 
\lipsum[1-5][1-13]\par} 
The \verb|\intextsep| return now to \the\intextsep. \lipsum[6][1-13] 
\end{document}
```